# GLM Diganostic Analysis - What plots actually matter?

Tags: regression, generalized-linear-model, diagnostic

In regards to this Poisson approach ([How can the Poisson GLM be used instead of logistic regression for the Titanic survival data?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/186949/how-can-the-poisson-glm-be-used-instead-of-logistic-regression-for-the-titanic-s?noredirect=1#comment355119_186949)).

I always thought that Normal Q-Q, Cook's D distance plots were extremely important in order to assess any kind of model. The lecturer however mentioned that in this case an "Absolute" Deviance Residual Plot was enough.

(i) I am wondering why? I thought that the absolute value of the residuals versus the linear predictor values is plotted to check whether the variance function of the chosen error structure is appropriate. He said that it is not the issue that we are interested.

(ii) I am also wondering why use "Absolute Deviance Residual Plot" rather than the normal "Standardised Deviance Residual Plot?